# How to show for $x>1$, $\ln(x^2-x+1)+\ln(x+1)-3\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2x^6}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nx^{3n}}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Below question is 34 on page 149 of Edexcel Pearson's FP2 (Further Pure Mathematics 2.

> Show that for $x>1$, $$\ln(x^2-x+1)+\ln(x+1)-3\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2x^6}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nx^{3n}}$$

I have let $g(x)$ equal to the initial function, then done derivatives of $g$ to try to go towards a Taylor expansion around point $x=1$.

I then have $g(1)=\ln(2)$,  $g'(1)=-\frac{3}{2}$, $g''(1)=\frac{11}{4}$.

However my coefficients seem to be wrong.

I also see that $g(0)$ is not defined.

I am seeking:

1. An answer to the question using a Maclaurin or Taylor expansion with full working.
2. An explanation of which set of values of $x$ can be used for a Taylor expansion.

Comment: Hint: Put $x=1/u$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use well known series, you don't have to go through the trouble of setting up the series manually (via derivatives).

Simplify by using properties of logarithms:
$$\begin{align}\ln\left(x^2-x+1\right)+\ln\left(x+1\right)-3\ln(x) & = \ln\frac{\left(x^2-x+1\right)\left(x+1\right)}{x^3} \\[4pt]
& = \ln\frac{x^3+1}{x^3} \\[5pt]
&  = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\end{align}$$
And recall the standard series, for $|a|<1$:
$$\ln(1+a) = a - \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}-\ldots+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{a^n}{n}+\ldots$$
Note that $x>1 \implies 0<x^{-3}<1$; now use $a= x^{-3}$.